# Android Rivets Applink Data Always Null

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, applinks, rivets

I am using Rivets with Android to open my app and get data from a webpage.
I have the following in my onCreate method.

```
        if (Intent.HasExtra("al_applink_data"))
        {
            var data = Intent.Data.ToString();
            var appLinkData = Intent.GetStringExtra("al_applink_data");

            var alUrl = new Rivets.AppLinkUrl(data, appLinkData);

            // InputQueryParameters will contain our token
            if (alUrl != null && alUrl.InputQueryParameters.ContainsKey("an"))
            {
                _token = alUrl.InputQueryParameters["an"];
            }
            else
            {
               // No token found
            }
        }
```

My activity has this filter at the top.

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
    DataScheme = "test", 
    DataHost = "test", 
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    })]
```

My test content is test://test?an=1234, which successfully opens my activity. However, Intent.HasExtra("al_applink_data") is always false and Intent.GetStringExtra("al_applink_data") is always null. Intent.Data.ToString(); shows my content with the parameter. I am new to Rivets and Android programming in C#. Why might this always be false and null?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate(bundle);
  SetContentView(....);
  if (Intent != null) 
  {
   OnNewIntent(Intent);
  }
}

protected override void OnNewIntent(Android.Content.Intent intent)
{
  base.OnNewIntent(intent);
  var appLinkData  = intent.GetStringExtra("al_applink_data");
  AppLinkUrl alUrl = null;
  if (appLinkData != null)
  {
    alUrl = new Rivets.AppLinkUrl(intent.Data.ToString(), appLinkData);
  }
  if (alUrl != null) {
   // LAUNCH URI
  }
}
```

Remember to use the (lowercase) "intent" parameter passed in the OnNewIntent method:

intent.GetStringExtra("al_applink_data") ----> contains data 
Intent.GetStringExtra("al_applink_data") ----> return null.